# android: expand/collapse a recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerview` list. Each item in the `recyclerview` contains the following layout. Later when one clicks on the sample1 id, then `sample3.xml` should get inserted inbetween sample1 and sample2. For that I have created a linearlayout with id insertat in this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/sample1"
        android:text="Sample1"/>

      <LinearLayout 
      android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/insertat">
      </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/sample2"
        android:text="Sample2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`onclicking` id sample1 I want to insert a layout file `sample3.xml` inside `linearlayout` id insertat.

sample3.xml is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toinsert">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Sample1"
        android:id="@+id/sample3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I achieve this in recyclerview code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get exact requirement but , if you want just visible the view after on click, you can keep your layout by merge both as like below and can visible and invisible based on click event.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/sample1"
            android:text="Sample1"/>

          <LinearLayout 
          android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:visibility="gone"
          android:id="@+id/insertat">
              <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Sample1"
                android:id="@+id/sample3"/>
          </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/sample2"
            android:text="Sample2"/>

    </LinearLayout>





 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewbyId(R.id.insertat);
     mKeepPlayingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    layout.setVisibility(View.visible);
                }
            });
```

Comment: i was confused between invisible and gone. gone will hide properly.

Comment: android:visibility="gone" This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space in the layout.
android:visibility="invisible" This view is invisible, but it still takes up space in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

First get a reference of the insertat:

```
LinearLayout insertAtView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.insertat);
```

Inflate sample3 view:

```
View sample3View = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample3, insertAtView, false);
```

Then add sample3 to insertat:

```
insertAtView.addView(sample3View);
```

Full code:

```
findViewById(R.id.sample1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LinearLayout insertAtView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.insertat);
                View sample3View = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample3, insertAtView, false);
                insertAtView.addView(sample3View);
            }
        });
```